# Porque no funciona mi codigo en dispositivos mobiles

Tags: javascript, android, html, http, phonegap

Hice este html que se encarga de controlar unos relays en mi arduino. En la pc mi mac abriendolo con google chrome funciona perfectamente. Pero cuando lo compilo con phonegap y lo corro en android, las request GET no se envian. Pulso los switches y los relays no encienden. Alguien sabe a que se debe esto?

Les dejo mi codigo

```js
<span class="switch">
 <span class="switch-border1">
  <span class="switch-border2">
   <input id="switch1" type="checkbox"/>
   <label for="switch1"></label>
   <span class="switch-top"></span>
   <span class="switch-shadow"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-left"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-right"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-top"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-bottom"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-base"></span>
   <span class="switch-led switch-led-green">
    <span class="switch-led-border">
     <span class="switch-led-light">
      <span class="switch-led-glow"></span>
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
   <span class="switch-led switch-led-red">
    <span class="switch-led-border">
     <span class="switch-led-light">
      <span class="switch-led-glow"></span>
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
 </span>
</span>

<span class="switch">
 <span class="switch-border1">
  <span class="switch-border2">
   <input id="switch2" type="checkbox" />
   <label for="switch2"></label>
   <span class="switch-top"></span>
   <span class="switch-shadow"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-left"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-right"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-top"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-bottom"></span>
   <span class="switch-handle-base"></span>
   <span class="switch-led switch-led-green">
    <span class="switch-led-border">
     <span class="switch-led-light">
      <span class="switch-led-glow"></span>
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
   <span class="switch-led switch-led-red">
    <span class="switch-led-border">
     <span class="switch-led-light">
      <span class="switch-led-glow"></span>
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </span>
 </span>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

var ip = '192.168.0.104';

function on(id) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var url = "http://"+ip+"/r"+id+"=ON";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  var respo= xmlhttp.responseText;
 }

 function off(id) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
   xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  var url = "http://"+ip+"/r"+id+"=OFF";
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
  var respo= xmlhttp.responseText;
}

var checkbox = document.getElementById('switch1');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", comprueba, false);

function comprueba(){
  if(checkbox.checked){
      on(1);
  }else{
     off(1);
  }
}

var checkbox_2 = document.getElementById('switch2');

checkbox_2.addEventListener("change", comprueba2, false);

function comprueba2(){
  if(checkbox_2.checked){
      on(2);
  }else{
     off(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: ¿La aplicación tienes los permisos de internet?

Comment: Ni idea como se hace eso jaja yo solo use el html que cree en la pc y lo compile con phonegap

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas esto (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447566/phonegap-android-internet-not-working)

Comment: Debes añadir permisos a los servidores que vayas a realizar peticiones. Tienes que incluir los meta atributos que tenga tu código para que podamos compararlos

Comment: Aparte, eso parece una IP de una red local. A no ser que lo cambies, seguramente no funcione cuando lo pongas en un teléfono o tableta

Answer (score 2):

Como te pongo en los comentarios, esto se puede deber a diferentes motivos. Con la información de la pregunta me imagino que está relacionado con el primer punto de abajo, pero puede ser que también tenga que ver algo el segundo o el tercero:

1. La IP que compartes en el código (192.168.0.104) no es correcta. O mejor dicho, sí es correcta, pero es parte de una [red privada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_privada) (rango 192.168.0.0–192.168.255.255), por eso funcionará sin problemas en tu ordenador (conectado a la red privada) pero seguramente fallará en tu dispositivo móvil.

   Deberías comprobar que el dispositivo móvil tiene acceso a esa IP. Y si no lo tiene, en lugar de usar una IP privada, deberías poner la IP pública o la URL de tu servidor donde tengas alojado el servicio que controle la petición.
2. Debes especificar en las etiquetas meta una política de seguridad de contenidos ([content security policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy)), en la que especificar qué servidores podrán tener comunicación con tu app (traducción mía):

   > Controla qué peticiones de red (imágenes, XHRs, etc) se permitirá hacer (a través del webview directamente).
   >
   > En Android e iOS, la lista blanca de peticiones de red no puede filtrar todas las peticiones (e.g. `<video>` & WebSockets no se bloquean). Por eso, además de la lista blanca, deberías usar una meta etiqueta con la Política de Seguridad de Contenido en todas las páginas.

   Entonces, dependiendo de la versión de Android y Cordova que estés usando, vas a necesitar tener esa Política de Seguridad de Contenidos en tu(s) página(s) para que la petición GET funcione correctamente. En ese enlace hay algunos ejemplos, lo que quieres sería algo como esto:

   ```
   <!-- Permitir todo pero sólo desde el mismo origen o desde foo.com -->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' foo.com">
   ```

   En versiones anteriores de Cordova (4.x o menores), en lugar de usar las políticas de seguridad, tendrías que especificar el `access-origin` en config.xml pudiendo hacer algo como esto:

   ```
   <access origin="*" />
   ```

   pero deberías tener en cuenta que eso permitiría cualquier tipo de comunicación con cualquier servidor, lo cual puede ser excesivo (y poco recomendado), sería mejor concretar el servidor/servidores que tendrían acceso. Algo como esto:

   ```
   <access origin="http://midominio.com" subdomains="true" />
   ```

   para permitir comunicaciones con midominio y sus subdominios.